# Unity built in colour picker

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, color-picker

I am using Unity 2017 and I noticed that when I open the colour picker the color values appears in HSV values and not RGB.

On my second PC, the colour values are on RGB.

I have tried to look online how to change it, but Google doesn't seems to understand me and all the results are how to convert HSV to RGB in code.

All I want to do is set the built-in colour picker values to RGB

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Image component just above the colour sliders there is a small icon showing 3 colour bars (a coloured one, and two black/white bars), clicking on this will swap between HSV/RGB values

It looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/ce2028a43009407d8ba818320c7eea18)

In Unity 2019(alpha) they made it way clearer. If you click on the colour picker there will be a dropdown menu (located inbetween the colour wheel and colour sliders) with three options: HSV, RGB (0 - 1.0) and RGB (0 - 255)

Comment: No worries, its quite a small and easy to miss button!